# PayPal Auto Return Values

Tags: paypal

How do I send my own transaction ID with the original post and have **PayPal** return that variable with Auto Return values?  I have turned on Auto Return and I have the transaction ID.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your PayPal Standard code, add the `invoice` parameter and set it to your custom ID value.  That value will then come back in PDT / IPN so you can use it accordingly.

If you're going to be doing any post-payment processing (ie. updating database, sending email notifications, etc.) you'll want to use IPN for that instead of PDT.  Even with Auto-Return enabled there is no guarantee the user will make it back to your return URL, so then whatever code you have there wouldn't run.

Comment: I added invoice=9999 and this is what was returned  ?tx=7D49081826357222G&st=Completed&amt=85%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=